# REGEX para pegar informação dentro de uma string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Estou estudando PHP OO e parte do meu estudo está em montar uma Classe que trabalha uma template engine. Eu converti o arquivo para uma string com o file_get_contents e agora quero pegar uma parte dessa string pra gerar um LOOP.

```
{LOOP}
   <option value="%SEL-VL%">%SEL-TXT%</option>
{ENDLOOP}
```

Minha ideia é usar o preg_match para pegar o conteúdo que está dentro de {LOOP} e {ENDLOOP} e fazer as substituições das variáveis repetindo o bloco html que foi pego.

Preciso de ajuda para criar o REGEX que irei usar no preg_macth. Alguém pode me dar essa força?

Aceito ideias também... 
OBS: Não uso um framework pronto nem os template engine prontos e disponíveis na internet, pois esse desenvolvimento faz parte do meu estudo e prática de PHP OO.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela que entendi, sua pergunta se qualifica como [Lexer](http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP/) ou Interpretador.

Contudo você tem seu intervalo bem definido, apesar de não saber exatamente como você vai tratar isso depois.

Você pode usar a Regex :

```
({LOOP})(.*?)({ENDLOOP})
```

#### Explicação

- `({LOOP})` - Grupo `{LOOP}` - Identifica o inicio da captura.
- `({ENDLOOP})` - Grupo `{ENDLOOP}` - Identifica o final da captura.
- `(.*?)` - Grupo de Conteúdo - O mínimo possível para não ter problema com outro loop.

Seja em [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lxOeVj/1).

#### Problema

Por se tratar de um interpretador você pode acabar tendo o [seguinte problema](https://regex101.com/r/lxOeVj/2) em usar Regex.

#### Solução

O ideal seria trabalhar com [conversões](https://regex101.com/r/lxOeVj/4) recursivas, indo de dentro pra fora, depois que tiver tudo convertido, só fazer a oposto para montar a *string* final.

Comment: Para o intervalo bem definido, pose-se usar também: [(?<={LOOP})\s*(.*?)(?={ENDLOOP})](https://regex101.com/r/lxOeVj/5)

Comment: Eu já havia pensado nesse problema e tinha a ideia de uma solução com marcadores diferenciados... tipo {LOOP1} {LOOP2} e na instância ao executar o método eu informaria qual LOOP eu quero operar, inserindo ele no REGEX. 

Posteriormente separado o trecho entre o LOOP, eu converteria faria a substituição simples de Key => Valor pelas demarcações %%.

Ainda sou muito fraco em REGEX... não entendi bem a Solução.